# Git can't add folder, points to null

Tags: git

I'm using tower git, and for some reason, I can't stage/add a folder. I've tried it in the command line as well with "git add .", and for some reason, this folder is refusing to be added.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here's command line:
[image]

Comment: Git doesn't operate on folder levels, just files. If your folder doesn't have any file, git won't add it. Add an empty hidden file in the folder and use it instead. Also I should mention that you deal with `submodules` which are not "ordinary" directories, they are separate repositories which should be handled specially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vendors/STUtils` is a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** with a "dirty" content; you need to:

- go in that submodule, add and commit there (and push that new commit to the submodule remote repo).
- then go back to the parent repo, add (it will work this time) and commit, in order to record that submodule new SHA1.

Answer (score 1):

Git wont allow you to commit empty folders. Add a .gitkeep inside `Vendors/STUtils` and try again.

```
Vendors
└── STUtils
    └── .gitkeep
```